# In Spring Security, how to redirect registered users to index page if they want to enter login page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring MVC and spring security 4.0.2.RELEASE. I can assing a role and give a permision to the user, and after that user can access page with this code;

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/dba/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DBA')")
```

In my site, registered users should not access to login page and only anonymous users should be able to access there. If registered users try to access login page, they should be redirected to index page or another area. How can I do this?

Comment: how will u find out whether the user is registered or not without accepting user id?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways.

Probably your login page uri is processed by a controller method. The easiest way could be check if the user is authenticated inside the controller method and if true just made a redirection:

```
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(){
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication auth = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if(auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated()){
            return "redirect:/index";
        }
        else return "loginTemplate";
    }
```

You could also build an interceptor, to catch the request just before reaches the controller, and make the redirect in case the user is already logged in.